# Withdrawing monthly from a bank for 40 years

Tags: interest-rates, finance-mathematics, banks

Consider you have $\$104107.4099$ in the bank with a $.33\%$ monthly effective interest rate. You plan to withdraw a fixed amount X every month for 40 years, such that you make 480 withdrawals in total, without making any deposits.

I need to find X such that there will be $\$0$ in the bank after the last withdrawal.

My (tentative) work:

So after the first month we have $(104107.4099-X)(1+.0033)=Y_1$. After the second month we have $(Y_1-X)(1+.0033)=Y_2$. After the third month we have $(Y_2-X)(1+.0033) = Y_3$, and so on until we get to the last withdrawal $(Y_{479}-X)$.

I was thinking of using the future cash flows formula in some way:

$P(480)=104107.4099-X\sum_{k=1}^{479}(1+.0033)^k=0$.
But I know this does not work because we would only have interest on X.

Or

$P(480)=(104107.4099-X)\sum_{k=1}^{479}(1+.0033)^k$ but them solving for this gives you that $X=104107.4099$.

I am finding this problem very difficult, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am voting to close this question for being too basic as per quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. This topic is covered in the early chapters of most introductory textbooks such as Hull's "Options, Futures and Other Derivatives" or Sundaresan's "Fixed Income Markets and Their Derivatives".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a annuity calculation.

Present Value of Annuity $= \text{Payment} \cdot \frac{1-(1+r)^{-n}}{r}$

Therefore:

Payment = Present Value of Annuity $\cdot \frac{r}{1-(1+r)^{-n}}$

Present Value of Annuity $= \$\,104,107.4099\,;\,\,\,   r = 0.33\,\%;\,\,\, n = 480$

Monthly Payment $ = \$\, 432.5186$